# Ignore Null Value from XML script task

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I'm inserting  from table into object variable and  generating XML file using C# script.

But  I want to ignore the Columns based on any particular rows that has null values as only closing tags are coming for that.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
(new OleDbDataAdapter()).Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::VariableName"].Value);
```

and using foreach loop container to iterate data like this

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
```

Output:

```
OrderId ProductsID  ProductCategory ProductPrice    DiscountPrice   InventoryStatus
W11 Sqq1    NULL    NULL    9200    Yes
I22 LO99    POP1    9222    NULL    NULL
I111    JJI22   MDK3    8000    7500    No
Oll1    Okk1    IOIO9   8222    8000    Yes
OOO2    III8    YRYR2   NULL    7979    NULL
UOP2    UOW1    NULL    7911    NULL    NULL
PLL9    NULL    NULL    7822    7272    No
IKJ2    NULL    HK22    NULL    8989    Yes
Olk22   NOP2    OKL2    NULL    NULL    NULL
OLOL1   UDU2    NULL    9090    NULL    Yes
BOB2    NULL    ANP2    3000    2400    NULL
```

I want to generate tags for those column that has non-null values in xml files
Ex: O/p For 1st row in above table, only
OrderId ProductsID  DiscountPrice   InventoryStatus
W11          Sqq1           9200    Yes

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductCategory", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductPrice", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DiscountPrice", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("InventoryStatus", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"W11", "Sqq1", null, null, 9200, "Yes"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "I22", "LO99", "POP1", 9222, null, null});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "I111", "JJI22", "MDK3", 8000, 7500, "No" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Oll1", "Okk1", "IOIO9", 8222, 8000, "Yes" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "OOO2", "III8", "YRYR2", null, 7979, null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "UOP2", "UOW1", null, 7911, null, null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "PLL9", null, null, 7822, 7272, "No" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "IKJ2", null, "HK22", null, 8989, "Yes" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Olk22", null, "OKL2", null, null, null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "OLOL1", null, null, 9090, null, "Yes" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BOB2", null, "ANP2", 3000, 2400, null });

            XElement xRows = new XElement("Rows");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement xRow = new XElement("Row");
                xRows.Add(xRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    if (row[col] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        XElement xCol = new XElement(dt.Columns[col].ColumnName, row[col]);
                        xRow.Add(xCol);
                    }
                }
            }
            xRows.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
 
}
```